# XmlSerializer - Ignoring inherited unserializable member

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

Assume you have two classes, one inherits the other and the child needs to be serialized / deserialized with XmlSerializer. However, the parent contains a member that is not serializeable, say a dictionary.

```
public class Parent {

    public Dictionary<string, int> dictionary;
}
```

The parent class is a library used for many other scripts. It cannot be modified. Now the child class contains only serializable members:

```
public class Child : Parent {

    [XmlElement]
    public int foo;

}
```

When trying to call the serializer, I receive an error saying that the dictionary is not serializable. When trying to serialize in JSON, I managed to get away by the price of a warning. I just created another member with the same name and type, and used ScriptIgnore:

```
public class Child : Parent {

    public int foo;

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public Dictionary<string, int> dictionary;

}
```

I tried the same trick again here (by using XmlIgnore) but that didn't work on very well, the error was the same. The only way I managed to go through this is create separate classes that will only serve xml de/serializing and then copy the values back into the appropriate place.

Does anyone know a better way around this? Can I make XmlSerializer forget about the parent dictionary in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very first thing I would say, and always say: if serializing an existing model gets tricky - even remotely awkward, then ***stop doing that***. Take 2 minutes to create a separate DTO model, i.e. a model created *solely for the purposes of serialization* (and indeed, perhaps even tailored to a specific serializer). Now you put the exact right types, right members, right attributes, and right layout. All you need to do is add some conversion methods - static conversion operators work great here. So what I would say is: create a `ParentDto` and `ChildDto` (your names may vary); it'll take 3 minutes, and it'll work great.

Now, back to the question...

`XmlSerializer` looks at the declaring class for input; for both attributes and conditional serialization, no: we can't add those into the type model at this point. But there is another option - you can use `XmlAttributeOverrides` to pretend that there was an `[XmlIgnore]` on the dictionary member. However, some important caveats:

- the `XmlAttributeOverrides` API is a bit of a faff to use (see MSDN for an example)
- it is ***critical*** that you only do this *once*, and then store and re-use the `XmlSerializer` that you create this way; basically, if you *don't* do this, it will create a new dynamic assembly every time you `new` a serializer, and assemblies **never unload**, so you will haemorrhage memory; note that the *simple* usage (`new XmlSerializer(someType)` etc) has an inbuilt cache for this; but the `XmlAttributeOverrides` usage *does not*

But again, all this messing with `XmlAttributeOverrides` is a lot more work than just *creating a basic DTO*

Example of using `XmlAttributeOverrides`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
public class Parent {
    public Dictionary<string, int> WantToIgnoreThis { get; set; }
}    
public class Child : Parent {
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
static class Program
{
    static readonly XmlSerializer customSerializer;

    static Program()
    {
        var xao = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        xao.Add(typeof(Parent), "WantToIgnoreThis", new XmlAttributes {
            XmlIgnore = true
        });
        customSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Child), xao);
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        //var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Child));
        // ^^ this would fail

        customSerializer.Serialize(Console.Out, new Child {
            Foo = 123
        });
    }
}
```

Note in particular how the `static` field is used to cache the serializer.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement `IXmlSerializable` yourself and handle the specifics in `ReadXml(XmlReader reader)` and `WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)`. The `XmlSerializer` will call those methods if your class implements them instead of generating its own serializer.

```
public class Child : Parent, IXmlSerializable
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, int> Dictionary { get; set; }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Foo");
        writer.WriteValue(this.Foo);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {            
        var wasEmpty = reader.IsEmptyElement;
        reader.Read();

        if (wasEmpty)
        {
            return;
        }

        reader.ReadStartElement("Foo");
        this.Foo = reader.ReadContentAsInt();
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `IXmlSerializable` API (the read, in particular) is notoriously difficult to get right for anything outside of the trivial cases; so for anything complex, it either becomes a massive code-ache, or you end up having the overhead of a DOM API (`XmlDocument`, `XDocument`), simply to avoid the pain of writing a complex read method by hand. For my money, and I say this as someone who spends a considerable amount of time looking at serialization: implementing `IXmlSerializable` simply isn't worth the pain. YMMV, of course.