# XmlSerializer ignore all interface properties

Tags: c#, interface, xmlserializer

I have my model for serializing

```
public class User : EntityBase
{
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Questions:
How can I serialize my models by System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer without any interface properties (mean that it can be different model with interface properties)? Is it possible do without XmlIgnoreAttribute or any changes inside my model?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean system should ignore the attributes given?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XmlSerializer - Ignoring inherited unserializable member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588083/xmlserializer-ignoring-inherited-unserializable-member)

Comment: Not exactly, I meant that not only this model (this model for example), but now I know how to do it with Reflection. Thanks!